# How to separate a string into two, and then make one of those strings into a number [php]

Tags: php

I have this string:

```
"$string="Med0x2"
```

What I want, is to separate it into two strings, like this:

```
$string1="Med0x" ; $string2="2";
```

And then convert `$string2` into an int variable (covert from string to int)

How do I do this?

Comment: There are a lots of methods to achieve this. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = "Med0x2";
$string1 = substr($string, 0, 5);
$string2 = substr($string, 5);
$integer = (int) $string2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_match` for this, using capturing groups to get the parts of the string.
Something like this -

```
$string = "Med0x2";
$regex = "/^(.*?x)(\d+)$/";
if(preg_match($regex, $string, $matches)){
  $string1 = $matches[1];
  $string2 = $matches[2];
  $integer = intval($string2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to Find sub string in first va

```
$string1 = "Med0x2";
$string2 = (int) substr($string1, -1);
echo "$string2";
echo is_int($string2) ? "yes":"no";
```

Comment: this assumes the number is always going to be 1 digit